# Installing plugins to CKEditor 5 in Laravel 5 with webpack

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, ckeditor

I have got a small issue with installing plugins to CKEditor integrated to Laravel 5.6.
According to integration guide from CKEditor document, I was able to add [`@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic) dependency using npm to the project and it was working just fine with webpack.

But the problem is that I can't add custom plugin which is not included to the CKEditor by default. I'm following the [guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html) to add custom plugin but it's not really working fine with webpack in laravel itself. For example, I tried to add `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment`, but didn't work and I got the following console error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

I guess this could be something that I have not added all necessary plugins when setup ClassicEditor instance. So I tried another thing.
I have installed the plugin to ckeditor build and I got the custom build. But when I'm trying to import the build in the custom path with the following statement, it's not importing.

```
import ClassicEditor from '../plugins/vendor/ckeditor/build/ckeditor';
```

If I just remove build directory from node_modules and copy this custom build, I am able to make it work with the following statement.

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor';
```

This is not a professional way to edit/update in node_modules.

So my question is:

> How can I install custom plugin to CKEditor on Laravel itself?
>
> Or how can I add the custom CKEditor build to the project without customizing node_modules?

Comment: I run the same issue. I followed the guide "Installing plugin to editor", importing is good, my IDE recognize the plugin and the compiling runs smoothly but then in my browser's console I see :

modules[moduleId] is undefined

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? If so, may you share it?

Answer (score 1):

I have used CKEditor among others in my Laravel projects, but here is how I went about it:

1. I downloaded the js and CSS files from CKEditor website and unzip the files
2. I copy those files in the public folder of my Laravel Project
3. You can access and use them in your blade pages like this

```
<code>
   <script src="{{asset('js/ckeditor.js')}}"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet: href="{{asset('js/ckeditor.js')}}" />
</code>
```