# Installing CKEditor plugin in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, npm, ckeditor, laravel-mix, ckeditor5

I am working on a Laravel project that uses the CKEditor WYSIWYG editor.
The problem I ran into is that I can't resize an imported image in the editor itself. I found out that I need to install custom plugins for each missing functionality in the official documentation. But so far, I could not find a way to import any of the official plugins into my Laravel project.

My current configuration is:

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
window.ClassicEditor = ClassicEditor;
```

> With this content of app.js, the CKEditor works fine without using
> plugins.

Then I tried  adding an import for the specific plugin:

```
import ImageResize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageresize';
window.ImageResize = ImageResize;
```

But that resulted in throwing an error: `Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules`
It also provided [link](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules) to their documentation containing that error, where I realized that you could import the source file (`@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor/src/classsiceditor`) or the build file (`import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';`), but here is where my understanding of what is going on faded away.

Anyway, I also tried using the plugin in the view:

```
ClassicEditor.create(
      allEditors[i], {
        plugins: [ ImageResize],
        extraPlugins: [SimpleUploadAdapter]
      }
    );
```

But since it's not correctly imported, it doesn't really matter.

I also found Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326577/installing-plugins-to-ckeditor-5-in-laravel-5-with-webpack) from almost 3 years ago with similar problems, but no answers.

Meanwhile, I will also try some other WYSIWYG editors, and if any of those will be more promising will probably end up using one (I will let you know here).

**Update 1:**

*23.5.2021*

I downgraded to CKEditor version `4.9.2`, and image resizing works right out of the box, no plugins needed. It's a very temporary solution, but it works.